# How to set routing between laravel and custom module?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I have two modules one is a Laravel Extension and Second one is custom module(just some html,css,js file).

I have created Two folders as its project requirement.
Let say Folder1(basic bootstrap home page) and Folder2(complete laravel Application).

```
Website Root

Folder1
--index.html
--css 
--js

Folder2
--app
--config
--database
--other laravel foldes
```

> How can configure routes so that from index.php I can call some
>   controller of laravel with is in `Folder2`.
>
> And From some view of laravel redirect to index.php in `Folder1`

I know its not perfect way to do that but its requiremnt of client and we cann't change that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Do following steps make sure you have backup.

1.Put all content folder public folde to root folder so that laravel can understand this is your root.

2.Edit `index.php` and provide file path to them

```
require __DIR__.'folder2/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'folder2/bootstrap/app.php';
```

3.Now laravel routing is working here. so all your laravel routs are now filne.

4.Now for all html files in folder1 you can make a `.htaccess` rules or make a general rule in root folder.

```
Redirect 301 /home /folder1/home.html.
```

5.Now when you access site.com/home it will redirected to folder1 and when you access site.com/laravelHome it will go to folder2.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Puli](http://docs.puli.io/en/latest/) and add your module Folder1 as a resource.

They have a twig extension too so using it in a Laravel should be pretty seamless